# Material Angular md-autocomplete clear and blur after selection (multi select)

Tags: blur, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I am trying to use md-autocomplete in Angular Material as a multi selector. The idea is, that the selected element from the autocomplete will be added to an object array after selection and then the selection will be removed from the md-autocomplete. I was able to clear the md-autocomplete, but the focus stays on the md-autocomplete input and so the autocomplete suggestions are still visible.
Example:
http://cdpn.io/QjQGVQ

Code:

```
function selectedItemChange(item) {
  $log.info('Item changed to ' + JSON.stringify(item));
  if(item)
  {
    //check if item is already selected
    if($filter('filter')(vm.contactsSelected, function (d) {return d.id === item.id;})[0])
      {
        $log.info('Item already selected. Will not add it again.');
      }
    else
      {
        //add id to object
        vm.contactsSelected.push(item);    
      }
    // clear search field
    vm.searchText = '';
    vm.selectedItem = undefined;

    //somehow blur the autocomplete focus
    //$mdAutocompleteCtrl.blur();
  }
}
```

PS: I am aware I could use the contact chips of Angular Material instead, but I was still wondering how the blur could be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

If you set md-no-cache="true" property inside your  the list will dissapear, but input field will not be cleared. I think is better solution than clearing input field but leaving the list visible, but is up to you.